# Nodejs server crashing ONLY after disowning process from SSH terminal and closing the session. Process runs but overloads on CPU

Tags: node.js, ssh, server, cpu

I am running nodejs server on a remote ubuntu server. For some strange reason, when I disown the process in the SSH tunnel then close the terminal, then try to use the site, the server locks up completely then if I reopen the SSH tunnel or have a second one running same time I can use `ps aux` to see the CPU running up to maximum load.

This ONLY occurs AFTER I disowned and quit the SSH tunnel, leaving the tunnel open guarantees the server stays stable for hours, then I can reproduce this consistently by then closing the session with the process disowned and refreshing the page. If I close a second SSH terminal that did not start the process, that does not have any effect, it's only after closing the SSH tunnel that I started the node process from.

This is the basic workflow that reproduces this bug every time for me:

Via SSH tunnel to a ubuntu server:
Run `node server.js &`
Then `disown -h`
Then close SSH
Refresh page
Wait a minute, server is locked up, or reopen SSH tunnel right away and see the CPU load ticking up from ZERO to 100% via `ps aux`. Server is completely stable otherwise until I've closed the terminal, no issues locally or remotely otherwise, and the server itself is uncomplicated.

Tried GPT for an opinion and it says there might be some resource issue with the SSH tunnel and running the node process but that doesn't really help me find a solution.

If it works I should have no issues disowning the process and closing the SSH tunnel to leave the server running. I have never encountered this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior suggests that there might be a connection or resource issue related to the SSH tunnel and running the Node.js process. I can give you some advice for further debugging:

1. Check for any error messages: When the server locks up or crashes, there might be error messages or logs generated that can provide insight into the problem.
2. Monitor system resources: Before and after closing the SSH tunnel, monitor the system resources such as CPU, memory, and network usage. This can help identify any abnormal resource consumption or bottlenecks that could be causing the issue.
3. Examine the SSH configuration: Review the SSH configuration on both the server and client side. Check if there are any specific settings or restrictions that could impact the stability of the SSH tunnel or the Node.js process.
4. Consider using a process manager: Instead of manually running the Node.js process and disowning it, you might try using a process manager like PM2. And also don’t forget to always check the dependencies.

Comment: Also, you can try different OS: Windows, Linux, or macOS, to check, maybe somewhere it works!